# query internal state of component using useState with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am using enzyme 3.9.0.

I have just refactored a class component to a component that uses the `useState` hook.

I was previously testing the component's internal state by extracting it like this:

```
const shortcutActions = wrapper.state().shortcuts;    

expect(shortcutActions).toHaveLength(1);
```

Is it possible to query the internal state when `useState` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks are brand new and Enzyme is being updated to support them.

You can follow the general progress here: [Issue #2011](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011).

Support for `useState` in particular is being tracked here: [Issue #2008](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/2008).

So the current level of support for `useState` is:

- `mount` supports `get` and rendered element update with `set`
- `shallow` supports `get`, but does not yet support rendered element update with `set`

---

As for querying the internal state directly, I'm not sure that is necessary.

From [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#hooks-and-function-components):

> Hooks **don’t** work inside classes. But you can use them instead of writing classes.

...so hooks *only* work in what `React` prefers to now call `"function components"`.

Any state defined using `useState` will exist only inside the function body and will not be accessible to anything outside the function.

The only way to modify that state is by interacting with the rendered output that the function returns, so testing a function component should just involve interacting with the rendered component and verifying that it re-renders as expected.